# Android: Get the number of lines from textview after orientation change

Tags: java, android, textview, android-orientation

Currently I have a `framelayout` that has it's background color determined by the number of lines in a `textview` that it holds. If the number of line exceeds 2, then I want to have a different background color. For screen orientation changes, I want to recalculate what the background color inside the `onConfigurationChanged` method. When I call `getLineCount()`, I am still getting the number of lines from prior the the orientation change. In other words, the lineCount will return the lineCount from prior to the orientation change.

It will always lag behind by one orientation change. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Can you show your code first?

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
int lineCnt = textView.getLineCount();
```

with [handling orientation change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)
Basically, there are 2 ways to handle it.
One require restart on your activity, another one doesn't. I have read comments that restart activity is recommanded.

If you

> you might encounter a situation in which restarting your application and restoring significant amounts of data can be costly and create a poor user experience

You may consider not restarting your activity by doing following:

In xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

In activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```